# How to obtain our token's current price

Tags: stellar-sdk, horizon

We issued a token on Stellar using stellar API. We need to show the price of our token on our website. How we can do that? Is this available using Stellar API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the orderbook for the pair you want to know the price like XLM/YOURTOKEN then get the first ask and bid from the list of results, from there you can calculate the average or use the lowest asking price.

XLM/TOK

https://horizon.stellar.org/order_book?buying_asset_type=credit_alphanum4&buying_asset_code=TOK&buying_asset_issuer=GA23456&selling_asset_type=native